# .NET Core Web App doesn't break on exception, and no details in exception

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have a new .NET Core 1.0 project, and for some unknown reason it has stopped (or never did, I do not recall) breaking when debugging.

I've added the StackTrace package here: [How can I get the line number and file name from an exception in net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39757823/how-can-i-get-the-line-number-and-file-name-from-an-exception-in-net-core?rq=1)

But with no success.

I'm using VS2015 community and the standard tooling from there.

A potentially relevant snippet from my `project.json` file:

```
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "define": [ "DEBUG", "TRACE" ]
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
```

---

**UPDATE**

OK, if ou start with a new Core Web Application everything works as expected.

If you then update all the packages, it'll fail to build until you add:

```
"runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win81-x64": {},
    "win8-x64": {},
    "win7-x64": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win81-x86": {},
    "win8-x86": {},
    "win7-x86": {}
  },
```

To the `project.json` to get it to build and launch.

By doing this, I can now get line number but still no breaking. My new test project works as expected. I'll have to go through and see the differences.

Comment: You're not running in release mode are you?

Comment: Nope, checked everywhere and it's debug, debug, debug... There's a PDB file being created as well... Baffling!

Comment: Are you doing remote debugging? (i.e. hosting x64 version on remote server)

Comment: Nope, all local... Even running off a local drive, using IIS Express. I've tried with the console app with the same results.

Comment: Both editions of .NET Core installed? (x64 and x86)? And does it only fail on x64 or on x86 too?

Comment: Not sure tbh... But just created a new project, and everything works and vs breaks on exceptions. I've copied over most of the project.json and now have lines in the exception details, but still no breaks in vs... Getting closer!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It appears to be that somehow the exception details were unchecked.

I reset all of the `project.json` dependencies, which meant I received detailed exceptions on the error pages, however VS still didn't break.

By checking the below:

[image: Exception details window]

It's now working correctly. I do not know if that is overkill, and if it's CORE specific, or per project, or something in VS (given a new CORE project did break it makes me think it's per project).

Comment: Thank you, I was going crazy. That did it.